# Create table by grouping mean values by column and list of one-hot encoded columns (Python, pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with tweets and I would like to report the **mean sentiment score** *by topic* and *by community*.

This is what my dataframe looks like where each row is a document (tweet):

```
tweet_text        sentiment  community_id   topic_1   topic_2   topic_3    ...    topic_k
"blah blah blah"      0.7      1233             1       0         0        ...       1
"blah blah blah"     -0.4      9845             0       1         1        ...       0
"blah blah blah"      0.1      1233             1       0         1        ...       0
```

I want to create a dataframe that contains a mean sentiment value in each cell like this:

```
community_id   topic 1   topic 2   topic 3   ...    topic k
 1233           0.1       -0.8       0.5     ...       0.9
 9845          -0.3        0.2       0.4     ...       0.1
 ...            ...        ...       ...     ...       ...
```

Any thoughts on how to go about this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you want to propagate the sentiment through the topic, then average out by `community_id`:

```
(df.filter(like='topic')
   .mul(df.sentiment, axis=0)
   .groupby(df.community_id)
   .mean()
)
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks like it is filtering by a single topic at a time. How do I get it to generate these columns for all topics? Put it in a for loop and append each additional topic column?

Comment: No it’s not. It does all the columns with names containing `topic`. You can also replace the first line (`df.filter(...)`) with `df[list_of_topics]`

Comment: Thanks!This is the final code that I used:
`topics_list = ['topic_1', 'topic_2, 'topic_3']
df[topics_list ].mul(df[sentiment], axis=0).groupby(df[community)d]).mean()`